# Выгрузка метаданных из sas dis

Tags: sas

коллеги!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу выгрузить метаданные джобов и таблиц из sas dis?

Желательно, с помощью внешнего языка, или есть ли возможности сделать это в самом sas dis?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос немного двусмыслен, я понял его как "выгрузить с помощью DIS или внешнего языка метаданные о джобах и таблицах с метасервера".

Для доступа к метаданным есть разные API; конкретно для этой цели лучше подойдет [proc metadata](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrmeta&docsetTarget=p1uow4279pnog1n1cyz5ak66kf2s.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).   Нужно будет сформировать запрос к метаданным в виде XML, и также в виде XML будет возвращен ответ.  Затем можно превратить его в реляционный вид с помощью [XML map](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=engxml&docsetTarget=p0b4dnu019ycsxn11k3savd51h6k.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).

Тот же запрос можно выполнить из внешнего клиента Open Metadata Interface, например [на Java](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=omaref&docsetTarget=p0d2drjj7p068fn16ljtzci0qvpb.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) или [.NET](https://github.com/paulhomes/DotNetOMIDemo).  В этом случае разбор XML нужно будет сделать средствами этого внешнего языка.